# Oracle Forms Get Value and Column ( as Parameter to Send ) That I Write the Value Between F11 and Ctrl + F11 for Filtering Tabular List

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracleforms

I have a tabular list that has two columns (id, name).
I filter tabular list by writing a value between f11 and ctrl + f11. Sometimes I filter it with id, sometimes with name.
After filtering, I push a button. When I push this button I want to get value and column that I wrote this value between f11 and ctrl + f11. Result should be like: ' id:null, name:"Alice" ' or ' id:22, name:"" ' according to which column I fill.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Huh, doesn't make much sense to me. You **see** it on the screen when you get the results, don't you?

Anyway: try with `GET_BLOCK_PROPERTY` built-in, check its `ONETIME_WHERE` and/or `LAST_QUERY` properties which will return how the last `where` clause (or the entire query) looked like.

You'll have to parse it in order to get values you want. It can be done, will require some typing, maybe you'll have to involve a stored procedure and its advanced features such as regular expressions and stuff (which might not be supported by Forms' PL/SQL engine).

Once again: I wouldn't do it, but - if you have & want to - go for it.